# Sqlite "where" statement not writing to NSMutableArray

Tags: ios, sqlite, uipickerview

Can anybody help, I am trying to use a `WHERE` statement to select data from a SQLite DB & write to a `NSMutableArray` so the user can select reduced amount of data from a `UIPickerView`, simply they use a picker to select a Region, then the `SELECT` statement looks at the `UITextField` with the Region they have selected & picks the stores in this Region.

If I use the code below, I get no data in the picker, if I reduce the result to one answer & write the result to a `UITextField` I get the data, if I remove the `WHERE` statement I get data in the picker but every store in the DB, not just the ones in the Region.

```
- (void) findStoreName{ storeFullName = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
    const char *dbpath_rm1 = [databasePath UTF8String];
    sqlite3_stmt *statementrm1;
    if (sqlite3_open(dbpath_rm1, &storeData) == SQLITE_OK) {
        NSLog(@"RM Names db opened");
        NSString *querySQLPrm1 = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"SELECT Store1,Store2 FROM storeNames WHERE RM_N=\"%@\"",rmName.text];
        const char *query_stmtrm = [querySQLPrm1 UTF8String];
        if (sqlite3_prepare_v2(storeData, query_stmtrm, -1, &statementrm1, NULL) == SQLITE_OK)
            while (sqlite3_step(statementrm1) == SQLITE_ROW) {
                NSString *rm1 = [[NSString alloc] initWithUTF8String:(const char *) sqlite3_column_text(statementrm1, 0)];
                NSString *rm2 = [[NSString alloc] initWithUTF8String:(const char *) sqlite3_column_text(statementrm1, 1)];
                NSString *str = [[NSString alloc]initWithFormat:@"%@",rm1];
                [storeFullName addObject:str];

                NSString *str2 = [[NSString alloc]initWithFormat:@"%@",rm2];
                 [storeFullName addObject:str2];}
        sqlite3_finalize(statementrm1);
    }
    sqlite3_close(storeData);NSLog(@"RM Names db Closed");
}
```

---

Update:

This is the `IBAction` code that calls the above method:

```
- (IBAction)acessdbStore:(id)sender {
    [self findStoreName]; 
    [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:NULL]; 
    [UIView setAnimationDuration:0.3]; 
    dbStoreview.frame = CGRectMake(300, 430, 380, 288);
    [UIView commitAnimations]; 
}
```

Comment: are you initializing your NSMutableArray ?

Comment: I had a quick surf to understand your question and the answer would be no, is this required for all table arrays ? because as I said if I remove the Where statement the NSMutableArray populates with data, what should the code look like & when should it go, many thanks

Comment: I meant doing storeFullName=[[NSMutableArray alloc]init]; before adding any objects.btw if it gets filled if you remove the where statement then it means you are initializing it somewhere. So the problem is in the where statement. Consider doing WHERE RM_N='%@' instead of WHERE RM_N=\"%@\"

Comment: @"SELECT Store,Store2 FROM storeNames WHERE RM_N='%@' ",rmName.text];

Comment: Are you saying it should look like above?

Comment: Yes ! It should work this way. If it doesn't try setting a breakpoint to check whether any results are returning as result from this query or not !

Comment: thank you for your time, but sadly it made no difference, I am not an expert so I will have a read up on using "breakpoint"

Comment: no problem but do check the where statement you used to comment here you had a typo in your statement @"SELECT Store,Store2 FROM storeNames WHERE RM_N='%@' ",rmName.text]; <- You typed this over here while in your code above you had -> @"SELECT Store1,Store2 FROM storeNames WHERE RM_N=\"%@\"",rmName.text so is the column name Store or Store1 ? Check out for this and if it helped a little bit don't forget to upvote my comments :)

Comment: and do consider having a look at this tutorial It will help u alot http://www.raywenderlich.com/913/sqlite-tutorial-for-ios-making-our-app

Comment: I had continued to try & find a solution, I have column's "Store" right through to "Store24" & was just changing them around, it was a keen eye spot, but not what is causing me the problem, is there a way to write what is in the NSArray's to the log?

Comment: Yes ! In your case -> for(NSString *cStr in storeFullName) { NSLog(@"%@",cStr)};

Comment: thank you, I will also have a read through the "raywenderlich" link

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Having updated the question with the code that calls this `findStoreName`, the issue is that when done retrieving the data, you must instruct your picker view to invoke the datasource/delegate methods to reload the data:

```
[self.dbStorepicker reloadAllComponents];
```

---

We cannot speak to the precise behavior without seeing example data from the table, as well as seeing the code that invokes this function.

But having said that, this code, if it encounters any problem, will silently fail without providing any meaningful diagnostic information. If any of these SQL calls fail, I would advise logging (a) the return code, `rc`; and (b) `sqlite3_errmsg()`:

```
- (void) findStoreName{
    NSMutableArray *storeFullName = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
    int rc;
    const char *dbpath_rm1 = [databasePath UTF8String];
    sqlite3_stmt *statementrm1;
    if ((rc = sqlite3_open(dbpath_rm1, &storeData)) != SQLITE_OK) {
        NSLog(@"open failed (%ld)", (long)rc);
        return;
    }

    NSLog(@"RM Names db opened");
    const char *query_stmtrm = "SELECT Store1,Store2 FROM storeNames WHERE RM_N=?";
    if ((rc = sqlite3_prepare_v2(storeData, query_stmtrm, -1, &statementrm1, NULL)) != SQLITE_OK) {
        NSLog(@"prepare failed: %s (%ld)", sqlite3_errmsg(storeData), (long)rc);
    } else if (sqlite3_bind_text(statementrm1, 1, [rmName.text UTF8String], -1, NULL) != SQLITE_OK) {
        NSLog(@"bind failed: %s (%ld)", sqlite3_errmsg(storeData), (long)rc);
        sqlite3_finalize(statementrm1);
    } else {
        while ((rc = sqlite3_step(statementrm1)) == SQLITE_ROW) {
            NSString *rm1 = [[NSString alloc] initWithUTF8String:(const char *) sqlite3_column_text(statementrm1, 0)];
            NSString *rm2 = [[NSString alloc] initWithUTF8String:(const char *) sqlite3_column_text(statementrm1, 1)];
            NSString *str = [[NSString alloc]initWithFormat:@"%@",rm1];
            [storeFullName addObject:str];

            NSString *str2 = [[NSString alloc]initWithFormat:@"%@",rm2];
            [storeFullName addObject:str2];
        }
        if (rc != SQLITE_DONE) {
            NSLog(@"step failed: %s (%ld)", sqlite3_errmsg(storeData), (long)rc);
        }
        sqlite3_finalize(statementrm1);
    }
    sqlite3_close(storeData);
    NSLog(@"RM Names db Closed");
}
```

Note, I also eliminated the `stringWithFormat` to build the SQL, but rather used the `?` placeholder instead. And then I bound the text value to the `?` with `sqlite3_bind_text()`. This is likely to be unrelated to your current problem, but will be important to make your SQLite code more robust. (Right now, if the text string contained a quotation mark, your SQL would fail.)

The main observation is to log meaningful error messages if any of your SQLite calls fail.

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to respond, I will make the changes you suggested, I have added a log code & the correct results are getting logged, so I am wondering if it's a timing issues, i.e. the picker being displayed faster than the MSMutableArray results?

Comment: NSLog(@"storeFullName: %@", storeFullName);

Comment: @CoreyPowell The above `findStoreName` will populate the array. So, after calling `findStoreName` are you calling the picker's `reloadAllComponents`?

Comment: popped your changes in & still no details in the picker & no errors in the log, I added back the code to out put the MSMutableArray to the log & again the has the correct results?

Comment: No I do not have any code to reload All Components, What would this code look like, sounds like it might be my problem

Comment: - (IBAction)acessdbStore:(id)sender {
    
    [self findStoreName];
    
    [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:NULL];
    [UIView setAnimationDuration:0.3];
    dbStoreview.frame = CGRectMake(300, 430, 380, 288);
    [UIView commitAnimations];
}

Comment: `[self.pickerView reloadAllComponents]` will trigger your picker's data to be reloaded (replacing `self.pickerView` with the name of your control).

Comment: not sure what you mean by "your control" do you mean the ViewController name ?

Comment: Your `IBOutlet` for your picker view.

Comment: [self.dbStorepicker reloadAllComponents];  worked, really big thank you for sharing your knowledge

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT Store1,Store2 FROM storeNames WHERE RM_N LIKE \"%@\"
```

Have you tried this ? instead of RM_N = \"%@\"

Answer (score 0):

[self.dbStorepicker reloadAllComponents]; was my missing code, many thanks Rob for your help